# textbox switch with radio button on a modal dialog based partial view MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I try this action with that codes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=radio]").change(function () {
        var test = $(this).val();
        if (test.text == "Checkbox 1") {
            $('#dealer_terminal_id').hide();
        } else {
            $('#dealer_terminal_code').show();
        }
    });
});
```

---

```
  <div id="radio_buttons">
        <label>
            Terminal Code
            <input class="radio_button" id="radio_terminal" type="radio" name="radio" value="Checkbox 1" data-bind="checked: radio" />
        </label>

        <label>
            Dealer Code
            <input class="radio_button" id="radio_code" type="radio" name="radio" value="Checkbox 2" data-bind="checked: radio" />
        </label>
    </div>
```

Now, First; when I was hit the #radio1 in modal dialog, than has hidden the current field, that's good but, Than when I was hit to #radio2; modal dialog; do not anything and it was just stay.

Do I need to is modal page refreshing ? any ideas?
thanks.

Comment: You should add your `Answer` in the question as an Answer, and then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

Hi, I found the solution

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dialogDiv').hide();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name$='radio']").click(function () {
            var test = $(this).val();
            switch (test) {
                case 'rad1':
                    $("#rad1").show();
                    $("#rad2").hide();
                    break;
                case 'rad2':
                    $("#rad2").show();
                    $("#rad1").hide();
                    break;
                default:
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My html is :

```
 <div class="tableAssing" style="text-align: center">
    <div id="radio_buttons">
        <label>
            Terminal Code
            <input class="radio_button" id="radio_terminal_code" type="radio" name="radio" value="rad1" data-bind="checked: radio" />
        </label>

        <label>
            Dealer Code
            <input class="radio_button" id="radio_dealer_code" type="radio" name="radio" value="rad2" data-bind="checked: radio" />
        </label>
    </div>
```